# How does NSTableView modify the selection of NSArrayController via bindings?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nstableview, nsarraycontroller

Let's say I have the following situation:

[image]

When I select different rows in the NSTableView, it magically updates the NSArrayController (PersonController) selection. How is the NSTableView doing this? Does it do something like this:

```
- (void)bind:(NSString *)binding toObject:(id)observableController withKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath options:(NSDictionary *)options;
{
 if([observableController isKindOfClass:[NSArrayController class]]){
  // got the NSArrayController, which can be used to change selection
 } else {
  // not an NSArrayController, don't try to change selection
 }

 //...
}
```

I ask because I'm implementing my own bindable NSControl, and I'd like it to modify the selection of the bound NSArrayController like an NSTableView would.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On a hunch, I overrode `bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options:` on the `NSTableView` and both the `NSTableColumn` objects and made them log their bindings. This is the output:

```
Binding NSTableColumn["Last Name"].value to key path "arrangedObjects.lastName" of NSArrayController: 0x215fc0
Binding NSTable.content to key path "arrangedObjects" of NSArrayController: 0x215fc0
Binding NSTable.selectionIndexes to key path "selectionIndexes" of NSArrayController: 0x215fc0
Binding NSTable.sortDescriptors to key path "sortDescriptors" of NSArrayController: 0x215fc0
Binding NSTableColumn["First Name"].value to key path "arrangedObjects.firstName" of NSArrayController: 0x215fc0
```

Even though the only bindings I made were to "value" of the NSTableColumn objects, it looks like IB is adding additional bindings automatically. **`NSTableView` is able to modify the `NSArrayController` selection because it's binding `selectionIndexes` automatically in IB.**

This is confirmed in the [NSTableView Bindings Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/BindingsText/NSTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/NSTableView-DontLinkElementID_623), for both `selectionIndexes` and `sortDescriptors`.

Comment: Thanks so much for this detective work!  Working up the steam to write those overrides would have been painful.  Your work helped me a lot, I don't know why somebody rated the answer as less useful.